# Asymptotic analysis of nest loop with condition (j=i+1)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand the example for big O on this page: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   for (j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
      sequence of statements }
}
```

I don't understand why inner loop will run for `N` if `i=0`. If `i=0`, then `j=1`, and as the result, number of iterations for inner loop should be `N-1`. I understand why the complexity of this loop is `O(n^2)`. What I don't understand is why the inner loop starts with `N` number of iterations, not `N-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link has a slight error. Indeed the inner loop starts from `N-1` iterations rather than `N`, but the result remains the same.

Starting from that first mistake they miss 1 on each iteration. They forgot the +1 the `j=i+1` I guess.

Comment: Thank you. I understand why it's O(n^2). I don't understand why in the link I uploaded, the inner loop will start running with N, not N-1

Comment: @EminMammadov They have a slight error, but it does not change the result.

Comment: Yes. I thought the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `Big-O` for this is `O(n^2)`.

The outer loop is `O(n)` and the inner one is `O(n - 1)`.

So the effective time complexity is `O(n^(n - 1)) = O(n^2 - n)`.

Now for a larger value of `n`, the value of `n^2` will be significantly higher than that of `n` and the net result will be dependent on `n^2`

Hence the time complexity will be `O(n^2)`

Comment: I understand the complexity. I don't understand why in the link I uploaded, the inner loop starts with `N`, not `N-1`